# BelongsToMany relation. How to get unique rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent, unique, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have next `'member_companies'` table in DB:

[image]

And in model Member has a relation :

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'member_companies');
}
```

And it return me all companies with dublicates. For example, `Member::find(238)->companies->pluck('id')` return

```
[
  6,
  5,
  7,
  2,
  10,
  8,
  4,
  13,
  14,
  10,
  8,
  13
]
```

But I want only unique items. Like

```
[
    6,
    5,
    7,
    2,
    10,
    8,
    4,
    13,
    14,
]
```

How can I do it with eloquent relations?

Comment: Should the relationship also fetch other pivot columns like `branch_id`?

Comment: No. It should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found next solution:

```
public function companies()
{
    $relation = $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'member_companies');

    $relation->getQuery()->getQuery()
        ->joins[0]->table = \DB::raw('(SELECT DISTINCT member_id, company_id FROM member_companies) as member_companies');

    return $relation;
}
```

But maybe there is more delicate variant of this code?

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if its a new addition, but you can do this (at least in Laravel 7):

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'member_companies')->distinct();
}
```

If you also need to select a pivot column, make sure to use an aggregating function (eg: MAX, MIN, GROUP_CONCAT etc.). Otherwise, as there will be multiple rows / values for the pivot column, database server may throw (depends on configuration) error:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: its working perfectly in my case:

`return $this->belongsToMany(AnimatedObject::class, 'animated_object_pose', 'category_id', 'object_id')->distinct();`

Comment: This only works if you don't include any of the columns from the pivot table, i.e. you can't use `->withPivot()` or `->withTimestamps()`.

Comment: @miker MySQL (probably other database engines as well) doesn't allow selecting columns which are not in the 'DISTINCT' or 'GROUP BY' clause because there are multiple rows (and hence multiple values) for these columns for each distinct set returned.

Check MySQL's ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY config for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique) method in your controller:

```
Member::find(238)->companies->pluck('id')->unique('id');
```

Docs:

> The unique method returns all of the unique items in the collection. The returned collection keeps the original array keys
>
> When dealing with nested arrays or objects, you may specify the key used to determine uniqueness

Or in your relation you could use [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries):

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'member_companies')->groupBy('id');
}
```

Comment: Yes. But it is the way via collections. And in this way I receive unwanted information from DB. But I want to filter data when I request it from DB. It's must be something in relation

Comment: You could use this method in your relation, as well, this way you dont need to filter in your controller.

Comment: I can't. I receive next error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::unique()

Comment: My mistake, try using groupBy, i updated my answer.

Comment: I can't. I receive next error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #85 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by like this

```
Member::with(['companies' => function($query){
    $query->groupBy('id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Write please how I can use it in this relation:                                                        public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'member_companies');
}

Comment: You can apply groupby orderby and different condition on relation by this way, on calling companies function you're defining what data and how you want from that relation.

Comment: I must set strict => false in config/database.php. And it not good solution