# Fetching distinct or unique records from many to many relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to fetch relational count which is in `many-to-many` relation in my `Laravel 7.30` application. I've a `many-to-many` relational table named `project_associate_brand` which has `project_id`, `product_group_id`, `product_subgroup_id` and `brand_id`, so my table looks like:

```
project_id     product_group_id    product_subgroup_id    brand_id
   1                    1                     1               1
   1                    1                     1               2
   1                    2                     3               1
```

In the above table I want to fetch Groups with projects count so in my model `Group` I defined the relation as below:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'product_group_id', 'project_id');
}
```

and similarly I've relation defined in `Project` model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'project_id', 'product_group_id');
}
```

By defining the above relation I'm unable to get unique project counts since duplicate rows are present due to the table structure, so now I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55633472/belongstomany-relation-how-to-get-unique-rows?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and I added distinct in the relationship

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'product_group_id', 'project_id')->distinct();
}
```

Same in the `Project` model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'project_associate_brand', 'project_id', 'product_group_id')->distinct();
}
```

Also tried other options but it is not working through, maybe some elegant solution might be available which I'm unaware

Help me out, Thanks